# How do I write a matrix as a raw bitmap in R

Tags: r, image, matrix, plot, bitmap

**Not the problem:**
There are lots of folks who ask variations on "how do I save a figure" where the figure has borders, annotations, and style; I'm not looking for any of that because I can do it in base, lattice, or ggsave.  If you need me to, then I can make a list of 20 SO questions this isn't the same as.

**tl;dr**
I want to have a bitmap file where my matrix is the values. In python, using OpenCV I can read a matrix, and the pixel [1,1] is going to have a particular value.  If I change it, and save it, then that intensity value has changed.  How do I get that?

**Details:**
When I run this code:

```
set.seed(1)
img_data <- matrix(sample(x = 0:255, size = 228*228,replace = T),nrow = 228,ncol = 228)
image(img_data)
```

I get this image:
[image]

You can see the default annotation.  Annotation can be removed.

```
set.seed(1)
img_data <- matrix(sample(x = 0:255, size = 228*228,replace = T),nrow = 228,ncol = 228)
image(img_data, xaxt='n',yaxt='n')
```

And this looks less bad.

[image]

but opened in mspaint, it shows the problem.
[image]

Problems:

- White border around actual information
- image size is 789x503

I want an image that is 228x228, and the value [1,1] of the image is value [1,1] of the matrix.

How in base, lattice, ggplot, or something else R, does one make that?

**Update:**
This almost works.

```
set.seed(1)
img_data <- matrix(sample(x = 0:255, size = 228*228,replace = T),nrow = 228,ncol = 228)

mar_old <- par("mar")  #lets not permanently change values 
xpd_old <- par("xpd")  #lets not permanently change values 

bmp(filename = "mytest.bmp", width = 227, height = 228, units = "px")

par(mar=rep(0, 4), xpd = NA) 

image(img_data, bty ="n",axes=F,frame.plot=F, xaxt='n', ann=FALSE, yaxt='n', asp=1)
dev.off()

par(mar=mar_old, xpd=xpd_old)
```

It makes this image
[image]

It still leaves a white line on the right and lower edges when viewed in mspaint.
[image]

Perhaps bitmaps start their counting at zero??

**Update2:**

This almost works, and might be what I have to go with.

```
library(magick)

set.seed(1)
img_data <- array(sample(x = 0:255, size = 228*228*3,replace = T),dim = c(228,228,3))

img <- magick::image_read(img_data/255)
image_write(img, path = "mystes3.bmp", format = "bmp")
```

It gives this:
[image]

And in mspaint:
[image]

It has to have 3 layers, RGB (rgba?), to get converted.  This means it is a 3d array and not a 2d matrix.  It gets the size right in that it doesn't add padding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the `useRaster` parameter to `TRUE` in `image()`:

```
set.seed(1)
img_data <- matrix(sample(x = 0:255, size = 228*228,replace = T),nrow = 228,ncol = 228)

mar_old <- par("mar")  #lets not permanently change values 
xpd_old <- par("xpd")  #lets not permanently change values 

bmp(filename = "mytest.bmp", width = 228, height = 228, units = "px")

par(mar=rep(0, 4), xpd = NA) 

image(img_data, bty ="n",axes=F,frame.plot=F, xaxt='n', ann=FALSE, yaxt='n', asp=1, useRaster = T)
dev.off()

par(mar=mar_old, xpd=xpd_old)
```

I also corrected the height to 228 instead of 227.

[image]

Did a smaller image:

With `useRaster = T`

[image]

Without `useRaster`:

[image]

Without `useRaster` you even lose a row and a column.